# Form validation with react and material-ui

Tags: validation, events, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently trying to add validation to a form that is built using material-ui components. I have it working but the problem is that the way I am currently doing it the validation function is currently being called on every state change in the input (i.e. every letter that is typed). However, I only want my validation to occur once the typing has stopped.

Given my current code:

```
class Form extends React.Component {

    state = {open: false, email: '', password: '', email_error_text: null, password_error_text: null, disabled: true};

    handleTouchTap() {
        this.setState({
            open: true,
        });
    }

    isDisabled() {
        let emailIsValid = false;
        let passwordIsValid = false;

        if (this.state.email === "") {
            this.setState({
                email_error_text: null
            });
        } else {
            if (validateEmail(this.state.email)) {
                emailIsValid = true
                this.setState({
                    email_error_text: null
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    email_error_text: "Sorry, this is not a valid email"
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.state.password === "" || !this.state.password) {
            this.setState({
                password_error_text: null
            });
        } else {
            if (this.state.password.length >= 6) {
                passwordIsValid = true;
                this.setState({
                    password_error_text: null
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    password_error_text: "Your password must be at least 6 characters"
                });
            }
        }

        if (emailIsValid && passwordIsValid) {
            this.setState({
                disabled: false
            });
        }
    }

    changeValue(e, type) {
        const value = e.target.value;
        const nextState = {};
        nextState[type] = value;
        this.setState(nextState, () => {
            this.isDisabled()
        });
    }

    login() {
        createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password);
        this.setState({
            open: false
        });
    }

    render() {

        let {open, email, password, email_error_text, password_error_text, disabled} = this.state;

        const standardActions = (
            <FlatButton
                containerElement={<Link to="/portal" />}
                disabled={this.state.disabled}
                label="Submit"
                onClick={this.login.bind(this)} 
            />
        );

        return (
            <div style={styles.container}>
                <Dialog
                    open={this.state.open}
                    title="Enter Your Details to Login"
                    actions={standardActions}
                >
                    <span className="hint--right hint--bounce" data-hint="Enter in your email address">
                        <TextField
                            hintText="Email"
                            floatingLabelText="Email"
                            type="email"
                            errorText={this.state.email_error_text}
                            onChange={e => this.changeValue(e, 'email')} 
                        />
                    </span>
                    <br />
                    <span className="hint--right hint--bounce" data-hint="Enter your password">
                        <TextField
                            hintText="Password"
                            floatingLabelText="Password"
                            type="password"
                            errorText={this.state.password_error_text}
                            onChange={e => this.changeValue(e, 'password')} 
                        />
                    </span>
                </Dialog>
                <h1>VPT</h1>
                <h2>Project DALI</h2>
                <RaisedButton
                    label="Login"
                    primary={true}
                    onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap.bind(this)} 
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Is there a way that I can achieve my desired functionality, without making a major change to the code, or does it need to be completely refactored?

Comment: I would really recommend you to look into http://redux-form.com for this. here is an example: http://redux-form.com/5.2.1/#/examples/synchronous-validation

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Does the check have to happen after a certain delay? A solution that I think would suffice in most situations would be to split your code up a bit. Don't trigger your `isDisabled()` function in `changedValue()`. Instead have it run on the `onBlur` event instead.

Try this:

```
<TextField
  hintText="Password"
  floatingLabelText="Password"
  type="password"
  errorText={this.state.password_error_text}
  onChange={e => this.changeValue(e, 'password')}
  onBlur={this.isDisabled} 
/>
```

and then your function becomes:

```
changeValue(e, type) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const nextState = {};
    nextState[type] = value;
    this.setState(nextState);
}
```

Comment: At the moment there is no delay so the error message will show until the validation parameters are met but I want to make the check afterwards.

Comment: Afterwards when exactly? My answer above will check when the user "leaves" the textbox. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: onBlur isn't doing it isDisabled never gets called for some reason which I presume means that the onBlur event isn't firing??

Comment: That gives me an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Comment: It's weird how it worked before actually. If you change `isDisabled() {` into `isDisabled = () => {` it should work.

Comment: The problem is in changeValue I think, maybe I should avoid using nextState?

Comment: Yeah I fixed it, changed this.setState({nextState: nextState}) to this.setState(nextState); and it all works fine now! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 24):

Current Material-UI version doesn't use the `errorText` prop but there is still a way that you can use to display error and apply validation to the TextField in Material-UI.

We use the `error`(Boolean) property to denote if there is an error or not. Further to display the error text use `helperText` property of the TextField in the Material-UI, just provide it the error text you want to display.

Do it like:

```
<TextField
  value={this.state.text}
  onChange={event => this.setState({ text: event.target.value })}
  error={text === ""}
  helperText={text === "" ? 'Empty!' : ' '}
/>
```

Answer (score 12):

Simplest is to call `form.reportValidity()`. `form` can be obtained by calling `event.currentTarget.form`.

Answer (score 3):

This [library](https://github.com/vishalvisd/react-validator) that I had created, takes care of everything related to validating fields and it supports material-ui components as well...

To validate your fields, you just need to wrap you field component and you are done... saving a lot of effort in managing state yourself manually.

```
<Validation group="myGroup1"
    validators={[
            {
             validator: (val) => !validator.isEmpty(val),
             errorMessage: "Cannot be left empty"
            }, ...
        }]}>
            <TextField value={this.state.value}
                       className={styles.inputStyles}
                       style={{width: "100%"}}
                       onChange={
                        (evt)=>{
                          console.log("you have typed: ", evt.target.value);
                        }


     }/>
```

Comment: If you're going to promote your own libraries you have to declare it - see the [Stack Overflow behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: I have edited the answer, thanks for moderating and pointing out this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onblur text field event. It's triggered when input looses focus.

Comment: While your suggestion would work, it's probably better to update the value with each keystroke, but do the validation onblur instead.